# Using While Loops or For Loops

Tags: python-2.7

The computer uses 0 for False and 1 (among other values) for True. Let's sing the nursery song "Are we there yet?", and wait for an answer. If the human types in 0 then they are saying "False. We aren't there." When you finally get there, the human will type in "1" or True.

Your running code should look like this:
Are we there yet? 0
We aren't there yet.
Are we there yet? 0
We aren't there yet.
Are we there yet? 0
We aren't there yet.
Are we there yet? 0.
We aren't there yet.
Are we there yet? 0.
We aren't there yet.
Are we there yet? 1.
YAYYYY!!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question appropriately.

Comment: for loops in python are usually for iterating a item in list, but can also be used to run the same code over and over with one variable with a new value for each loop.   While loops are for running the same code until a certain condition is no longer True